# why Haskell can deduce [] type in this function

Tags: haskell, types

```
rho x = map (((flip mod) x).(\a -> a^2-1)) (rho x)
```

This function will generate an infinite list. And I tested in GHCi, the function type is

```
*Main> :t rho
rho :: Integral b => b -> [b]
```

If I define a function like this

```
fun x = ((flip mod) x).(\a -> a^2-1)
```

The type is

```
*Main> :t fun
fun :: Integral c => c -> c -> c
```

My question is, how can Haskell deduce the function type to b -> [b]? We don't have any [] type data in this function. Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`map` has the following type:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

So, we can deduce the types of the arguments to `map`:

```
(((flip mod) x).(\a -> a^2-1)) :: (a -> b)
(rho x) :: [a]
```

But the result of `map` is also the result of `rho x`, so:

```
(rho x) :: [b]
```

Which implies that `a` and `b` are the same type, so:

```
rho :: ? -> [b]
```

If we examine the mapping function, and make `x` free, we find the type:

```
\x -> ((flip mod) x).(\a -> a^2-1) :: Integral b => b -> (b -> b)
```

The `Integral b => b` gives us the type of `x`, and the `(b -> b)` unifies with the type of the function composition, so we know that this `b` is the same as the previous one.

```
rho :: Integral b => b -> [b]
```

Answer (score 6):

`(rho x)` must return a list because it is being passed to `map` and the type of the list element can be deduced from what is going on in the mapping.